# LINQ Query returning null results into anonymous variable

Tags: linq, null, return

What is wrong with my query code? It is returning null, it's no different to other examples I've looked at. What may be some of the reasons the "buildings" var is null.

The tables are not empty and should be returning some results.

**Tables in database:**

Buildings(BuildingId, BuildingName)

UsersBuildings(UserId, BuildingId, BuildingQuantity, BuildingLevel)

```
var buildings =
                from b in imDB.Buildings
                join ub in imDB.UsersBuildings
                on b.BuildingId equals ub.BuildingId
                where ub.UserId == userId
                select new { b.BuildingName, ub.BuildingLevel};
```

Comment: what is the value of userId? what does SQL Profiler tell you about the query being executed, and does that return results?

Comment: In your UsersBuildings tabel where is BuildingLevel column?

Comment: @devdigital UserId holds a valid integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BuildingLevel is in Buildings table so your query should be like

```
var buildings =
            from b in imDB.Buildings
            join ub in imDB.UsersBuildings
            on b.BuildingId equals ub.BuildingId
            where ub.UserId == userId
            select new { b.BuildingName, b.BuildingLevel};
```

Comment: Sorry to have wasted your time like that, another mistake of mine, I typed it in the wrong table. How can I look at the SQL Profiler like the other user suggested?

Comment: [For SQL Profiler this might be helps you](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21371/SQL-Server-Profiler-Step-by-Step)